# css animation using background property occurs abruptly

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve the effect of this image (the gif doesn't look very good :/ but basically there is a smooth transition where it changes from one color to another and back ):

[image]

this is my output (it looks like it makes the transition but abruptly starts again):

[image]

I have to achieve it using a total animation `time of 1000ms` and `ease-out`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get my animation to look the same.
my animation doesn't look the same as the gif, it looks a bit jerky

what is my problem?

```css
html,body{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}


.animation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: animationSkeleton 1000ms infinite forwards ease-out;
    animation-delay: 1ms;
}


@keyframes animationSkeleton {
    0% {
        background: #f6f6f6;
    }
    100% {
        background: #d8dada;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation"></div>
```

Comment: could you please explain what exactly the problem is here!!!

Comment: @Nikkkshit my animation doesn't look the same as the gif, it looks a bit jerky, I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may solve your problem

```css
html,body{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}


.animation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: animationSkeleton 1000ms infinite alternate ease-out;
    animation-delay: 1ms;
}


@keyframes animationSkeleton {
    0% {
        background: #f6f6f6;
    }
    100% {
        background: #d8dada;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation"></div>
```

Comment: what was the trick?

Comment: instead of using forward as animation-direction use alternate so that it could play the animation in both the direction.
`animation: animationSkeleton 1000ms infinite alternate ease-out;`